# target_link_libraries в CMake под Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, cmake

Пробую собрать кроссплатформенный проект используя CMake под Visual Studio 2017.
CMakeLists.txt выглядит так:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)

project(CMakeLibTest)

add_executable(mainApp App.cpp)

target_include_directories(mainApp PRIVATE ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Lib)
target_link_libraries(mainApp -L${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Win32/Debug -lLib)
```

Lib.lib уже собранная статическая библиотека, лежит в папке ../Win32/Debug относительно данного CMakeLists.txt и App.cpp.

При запуске сборки я вижу странные опции в командной строке линкера. Фрагмент командной строки линкера:

```
-LC:/Users/UserName/source/repos/CMakeLibTest/App/../Win32/Debug -lLib.lib
```

Линкер таких опций не понимает, и выдаёт warning:

```
warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/LC:/Users/UserName/source/repos/CMakeLibTest/App/../Win32/Debug'; ignored
warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/lLib.lib'; ignored
```

Ну и естественно в финале выдаёт ошибку:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl f(void)" (?f@@YAXXZ) referenced in function main
```

Правильные опции командной строки для линкера, которые должны получиться:

```
/LIBPATH:"C:\Users\UserName\source\repos\CMakeLibTest\Win32\Debug\" "Lib.lib"
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Как правильно прилинковать стороннюю статическую библиотеку в CMake под Visual Studio? И сделать это так, чтобы не поломать сборку на других платформах.
Или это баг в CMake?

(Я напрямую открываю CMakeLists.txt в VS: VS умеет работать с CMake напрямую, как с файлом проекта. Но если генерировать родные проекты VS через командную строку, то результат не измениться: в настройках сгенерированного проекта я вижу строки "-LC:/Users/UserName/source/repos/CMakeLibTest/App/../Win32/Debug;-lLib.lib;" которых быть не должно).

Comment: Укажите полный путь до этой библиотеки в `target_link_libraries`.

Answer (score 1):

[`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) может принимать
имя таргета-библиотеки, полный путь к библиотеке, имя библиоеки без префикса и расширения или опции ликовщика ничинающиеся с `-`.

Ваш скрипт пытается передать опции `-L` и `-l` о которых майкрософтовский ликовщик ничего не знает. Если очень хочется передавать опции, то используте существующие:

```
target_link_libraries(mainApp "-LIBPATH:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Win32/Debug" "Lib")
```

---

Но тогда ни о какой кросплатформенности речи не идет. Так как у того-же gcc эти опции другие. Лучшим вариантом будет использовать функционал CMake, инкапсулирющий в себе опции конкретных компиляторв/линковщиков:

```
target_link_directories(mainApp "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../Win32/$<CONFIG>")
target_link_libraries(mainApp Lib)
```

Comment: Есть проблема: в документации к CMake не рекомендуют использовать target_link_directories или использовать её только в крайних случаях.

Comment: Там говорится о том, что лучше использовать полный путь к библиотеке. Если вы отказались от `target_link_directories` в пользу передачи `-LIBPATH` в `target_link_libraries`, то вы ничего не улучшили, и даже немного ухудшили. Если у вас есть такая возможность, то, конечно, передавайте полный путь в `target_link_libraries`, это позволит системе сборки отслеживать изменения библиотеки, и пересобирать зависимые от нее таргеты по мере надобности. Если такой возможности нет, то не надо изголятся, с опциями комплятора, они ваш проект точно переносимее не сделают